# Different values configuration constants

Tags: angularjs

I have an AngularJS website in different environments (dev, prod). I also have some configuration constants that are different depending on the environment (i.e. to send requests to an API).

I have read many posts that solve this with Grunt by creating a dynamic file. Is there any other "more homemade" approach?

**UPDATE**
In the client side, Im runníng my AngularJS client application in an Nginx web server.

Comment: What are you using to serve your application? Because if your server is aware of its current environment it could generate some type of configuration for you.

Comment: You mean the server? Currently is node.js.

Comment: Well, you can pass en environment variable to your node.js server, and using it decide which configuration file serve to the client depending on your environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make your Node.js server decide which configuration file to serve to your client.

```
var app = express();
app.set('env', process.argv[2] || 'development');
//...

app.get('/libs/config.js', function(req,res){
     var env = app.get('env');
     if(env === 'development') {
        res.sendfile('config/dev-config.js');
     } else if (env === 'production') {
        res.sendfile('config/prod-config.js');
     } else {
        res.send(404);
     }
});
```

And in you angular client you do:

```
<script src="libs/config.js"></script>
```

And your servers you run your node doing

```
node app.js development
node app.js production
```

Also, I think Express has direct support to configure your current environment using `process.env.NODE_ENV`, so most likely, all you have to do is to set the `NODE_ENV=production` environment variable in your production Node.js server and you won't need to pass the configuration from the command line directly.

Comment: I have no idea about Node.js. I just donwloaded and started a default HTTP server. Anyway, I think I understand your approach. However I don´t know about express. I think my server is not using it (maybe I´m saying nonsenses). Please, find a plunker with my server http://plnkr.co/edit/2VESE6q26I0AyF2r81y4?p=info .

Comment: Hi Edwin, I finally migrated my AngularJS client from Node.js to Nginx. Do you know if I can follow the same approach. Any idea on the details?

Answer (score 0):

This is a hack, but my home made approach is to override the address of my API using a static hosts entry.

/etc/hosts

```
192.168.1.100    api.mydomain.com
```

It is dirty but it works.

Comment: thank you, but I think I cannot do this in production environment.

Comment: No, you would do this in your development environment.

Comment: I do this too. @Rober, do you have other constants you need to set? If so, perhaps you can provide some more information in an edit to your question that might get you a more complete answer.